# How to set object property in prototype function (scope problem)?

Tags: javascript, prototype, scope, this

This is something trivial, which I've forgotten.
There are possibly duplicates - I searched a little, found similar, but couldn't find as concise.

```
   String.prototype.test = function(){this.bar = this.length + 2;}

   var str = "foo";
   str.test();

   console.log(str);                         // foo
   console.log(str.bar);                     // undefined
```

Pretty sure it has to do with `this` being trapped in the closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has to do with the way you're creating your string in this case. Try:

```
var str = new String("Foo");
```

and you'll find it magically working. :-]

See an example at:
http://jsbin.com/odozo3/edit

Comment: I vaguely remember that the `new` keyword is needed for prototype methods.  Any ideas on how to get it working without specifying the object type (eg with just `var str = "foo";`)?

Comment: Simple answer @vol7ron: You can't.

Comment: Yeah, I vaguely remember that too. There are workarounds, but w/o any extra code there's no way to do it without late binding.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is that the string literal is not an object. But, behind the scenes, when you call a string function with literals, like "foo".toUpperCase(), what the javascript runtime does is wrap the string with new String("foo"). Anyway, this only happens when you call some pre build String function, not when you create a new one using prototype.

Edit: you only can rewrite a prototype of an object. That is why new keyword is necessary.