# Is there a way to customize/override assignment operations in JavasScript?

Tags: javascript, assignment-operator

> Every time I assign a *string*, I'd actually like to assign a *string object*, without the extra code.

This `var foo = "bar";`
becomes `var foo = new String("bar");`

Basically hi-jacking the assignment.

---

> **Follow-up:**
>   If the above is not possible is there a way to prototype the `string` variable type, rather than the String object?

As pointed out by [armando](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376314/armando), the `foo` would be a string type, but is essentially a customized array.  It would be nice to be able to prototype functions to that class.

Comment: @vol7ron: based on the questions that you have been asking recently, I think that you really want to be programming in Ruby. JavaScript doesn't support the kind of metaprogramming that you seem to be after.

Comment: [@Adam Crossland:](http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/226476/adam-crossland) My questions lately have no real merit.  It's been a while since I've done any intense JavaScript, so I'm just kind of getting back into it (I refuse to use `Prototype` or `JQuery`).  If `Ruby` could be run as part of a client-side web application, I would look more into it, but my focus is still on ECMAScript.  Server-side, I'm still a `Perl` devotee. :)

Comment: [@Adam Crossland:](http://stackoverflow.com/users/226476/adam-crossland) In your profile, your blog points to Google - intense :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to do this. Every string literal in JS has the same access to `String.prototype` functions as a String object. `"zomgwtf".toUpperCase()` works fine.

Comment: [This](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Strings_Reference) goes into a lot of detail about strings, literals and objects. Also, you might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756549/string-object-versus-literal-modifying-the-prototype) question informative.

Comment: [@MooGoo:](http://stackoverflow.com/users/375394/moogoo) I think the main reason I would like to know is for prototyping variables on-the-fly, see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757269/how-to-set-object-property-in-prototype-function-scope-problem)

Comment: [@sje397:](http://stackoverflow.com/users/338803/sje397) yes, that question/answer was very helpful! +1.  So would adding a closure to the property list keep it in `String object` mode?  Additionally, could you use a closure method to mimic a property value?

Comment: I give the answer at another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62627719/4437467

Comment: I give the answer at another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62627719/4437467

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No this is not possible
2. If it was possible, you really would not want to do this, at least not globally.

---

- The string variable type does not have all the extra overhead that an object does.
  **Note:** the string array that is created (in your case, `foo`) would have other properties (eg `foo.length`)
- Objects come at a performance hit

Comment: It is possible to override assignment to `Proxy` objects using [`handler.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set).

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite what you're looking for, but you may want to look at [Overriding assignment operator in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309585/overriding-assignment-operator-in-js)