# Overriding assignment operator in JS

Tags: javascript, cookies

```
var myObject = {"myKey" : "myValue"}
typeof(myObject.myKey) returns `string`

myObject.myKey = "newValue"
console.log(myObject.myKey) prints newValue
```

This is the expected behavior. But, similar value writes do not work for document.cookie

```
typeof(document.cookie) returns `string`
```

But performing `document.cookie = "value=123"`, appends to `document.cookie` string rather than set its value to `value=123`

So, how is assignment to `document.cookie` overridden?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`document.cookie` is a little magical, but depending on your browser constraints, you an use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define properties that have different *get* and *set* behavior.

For example:

```
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, "data", {
    get: function() {return this.val; },
    set: function(val) { this.val = JSON.stringify(val); }
});

obj.data = {a:1}; // Set as an object...
console.log(obj.data) // but retrieve as string '{"a":1}'
```

---

For example, to do something similar to the cookie example, you could make a function like:

```
var mixinExtender = (function mixinExtender(target) {
  var rawValue = {};

  Object.defineProperty(target, "data", {
    get: function() { return JSON.stringify(rawValue); },
    set: function(val) { 
      for(var key in val) {
        rawValue[key]  = val[key];
      }
    }
  });
})
```

This will mixin in a `data` property that will extend the *setter* value into a private object. The *getter* will return a serialized version of it. Then you could use it with:

```
var obj = {};
mixinExtender(obj);

obj.data = {a:1};      // Add "a" key
obj.data = {b:2};      // Add "b" key
console.log(obj.data)  // > {"a":1,"b":2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Browser-supplied host objects behave in ways that are not constrained by the semantics of the language. That is, `document` *looks like* a JavaScript object, but it's not. It's part of the runtime environment.

The JavaScript spec is written in terms of various internal "method" descriptions. Host objects like `window` and `document` have special versions of those internal methods. Thus, the runtime follows the spec as to how the `=` assignment process works, but the internal method `[[Put]]` is simply special.