# Javascript getters and setters for object, not object properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties, setter, getter

I know how to use JS getters and setters for object properties like so

```
var myObject = {
    value : 0,
    get property() {
        return this.value;
    },
    set property(v) {
        this.value = v;
    }
}
```

so that calling `myObject.property = 2` will set `myObject.value`, but what I'm wondering is if there is some way to call `myObject = 2` and still set `myObject.value` rather than changing `myObject` from an object into a number.

It's probably not possible, but javascript is an incredibly flexible language and I thought I'd pose the question to the community before I discarded the idea.

Comment: Discard this idea. `myObject` is a reference, and reassigning it to something else will... well, reassign it to something else.

Comment: It doesn't seen to be possible in JavaScript, although internally there's a `DefineOwnProperty` method, specified in the specification, which is only used when creating arguments for functions. The closest thing you can get is to use `DefineProperty` on `window`.

Comment: I think what you're really after here is overloading the assignment operator, which has been [discussed before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770480/is-there-a-way-to-customize-override-assignment-operations-in-javasscript)

Comment: @DaveNewton you can define getters and setters so when a reference is being assigned, it only executes the setter function and not actually assigning value to that property.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 That's pretty different than setting an arbitrary reference to something other than what you're setting it to. Or rather, it's different than making the assignment operator do something other than assign. This is baked into the language.

Comment: Oops. I downvoted this question thinking that it was an incorrect usage of property descriptors. I didn't know that you can define properties with getters/setters directly. and now my vote is locked. apologies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible indeed. Only for global variables though.

```
Object.defineProperties(this, {
    myObject: {
        get: function () {
            return myObjectValue;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            myObjectValue = value;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    },
    myObjectValue: {
        value: 0,
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
    }
});

myObject = 5;
console.log(myObject);
console.log(delete myObject);
```

Now, every time you assign a value to `myObject`, it shall actually run the `set` function and assign the value to the other property instead. Now, if you wanted to minimize pollution, you could create an IIFE and use variables inside that instead to hold the values, per se.

http://jsbin.com/zopefuvi/1/edit

And here is the version with the IIFE.

http://jsbin.com/puzopawa/1/edit

Comment: OP is asking about variables, not properties of the global object. Please explain how this works, and make clear what does get polluted.

Comment: @Bergi, variables are indeed properties of the global object, aren't they? And yes, this only works for global variables, naturally. And the second fiddle with the IIFE minimizes pollution to one property on the global object which would be the same as simply creating a global variable.

Comment: Yes, but *only* global variables are, and you don't want to use them in general, so this solution does not work for arbitrary variables.

Comment: True. I agree. Let me add that. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the situation I wanted to use it in is not global, but since this answers the question, I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note. I didn't know until reading this question that you could define getters/setters without `Object.defineProperty`. I was wondering at what the difference was between this 'shorthand' method, and defining getters/setters via `Object.defineProperty`.

I found, using the `myObject` example in the question:

```
var myObject = {
    value : 0,
    get property() {
        return this.value;
    },
    set property(v) {
        this.value = v;
    }
}
```

that `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(myObject, 'property')`

returns

```
get: ƒ property()
set: ƒ property(v)
enumerable: true
configurable: true
```

So worth mentioning is that `property` in this case is enumerable, meaning it will show up in loops.